# contiki cc2530dk border router questions

Tags: datetime, contiki

When I have generated the border-router.hex, and programmed the node with Flash Programmer,
run command `sudo ./tunslip6 -s /dev/ttyUSB0 aaaa::1/64`, there was such print information as show in the following, and no other further print, Could anyone has meet this? What is the problem?

```
user@instant-contiki:~/sensinode/contiki-sensinode-cc-ports/tools$ sudo ./tunslip6 -s /dev/ttyUSB0 aaaa::1/64
[sudo] password for user: 
********SLIP started on ``/dev/ttyUSB0''
opened tun device ``/dev/tun0''
ifconfig tun0 inet `hostname` up
ifconfig tun0 add aaaa::1/64
ifconfig tun0 add fe80::0:0:0:1/64
ifconfig tun0

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:127.0.1.1  P-t-P:127.0.1.1  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: fe80::1/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: aaaa::1/64 Scope:Global
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Comment: Please consider posting this on http://www.serverfault.com instead.

Answer (score 0):

This means that your PC is not getting any I/O from the device. Which on itself could have a lot of causes.